# How is Pulse Density Module (PDM) signal driven?

Tags: pulse, modulation

I am confused between Pulse Width Modulation (PWM) and Pulse Density Modulation (PDM).

From my understanding, both are used to transmit a digital signal into an analogue domain. It is basically doing a digital to analogue coversion. Is this correct?

In PWM, we generate an on-off signal at a fixed frequency. The On-period of the signal in each time period is what controls the amplitude of the resulting signal in the analogue domain. In this way, a digital circuit can output an analogue signal.

Now lets come to the PDM. Here also we have an on-off signal but there is no fixed frequency. How do we drive the PDM from lets say a sinusoid i.e when to turn it on and when to turn it off?

Comment: Additional discussion here: https://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/how-does-pulse-density-modulation-(pdm)-actually-work/msg4308223/#msg4308223

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PDM and PWM are same on average, but for one cycle, PWM packs all ones together and all zeroes together to make the PWM frequency, but PDM distributes the ones and zeroes across whole period.

As a concrete example, a PWM with 8-bit counter has a period of 256 time slots and when set to 50% duty it will output 128 time slots of high and 128 time slots low. PDM running at same clock for time slots will output a pattern of 256 time slots that alternate hi,lo,hi,lo etc so it also has 50% duty and equal count of high and low time slots during the same period.

Same with other PWM values, if the PWM is high for X time slots during the period of Y time slots, the PDM will also have the signal high for X time slots during period of Y time slots, but the high and low time slots are redistributed evenly over the whole period, instead of being packed together.

Answer (score 2):

PDM in some systems is the same as PFM in boost converters where the boost voltage is increased by reducing the interval between constant width pulses.

There is also an Arduino library for PDM audio.

It is basically V to f conversion then the reverse to restore V by integration.